# K Means based on mixed type dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have the following dataset and i want to apply clustering( in particular k-means) on it.

```
     id      category     value
0    122         A          3
1    122         B          4
2    122         C          9
3    145         A          19
4    145         B          22
5    145         C          90
.
.
. 
197    225         A          16 
198    225         B          17
199    225         C          12
```

What i want to do is to create cluster of id. For example each cluster should contain some id based on the similarity measure calculated on the category values.

For example: C1 {122, 145, 148}  C2{ 225, 222, 221} ....

Any idea on how to deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: What is the similarity criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)** your data into the appropriate shape:

Your categories should be *columns*, not separate rows.

```
     id          A          B         C
1    122         3          4         9
2    145         19         22        90
..
```

Don't forget to exclude the ID column for analysis! Never include IDs when clustering. For analysis, your data should have only columns A, B, C; one row per ID. So that you have an n x 3 matrix, then you can use k-means just fine.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that there categories from A-Z and there are many rows that belong to the same category. A K-means algorithm would work like outlined below. From your question it is not clear what is the similarity measure. I will update my answer once I get more clarity on what the clustering objective is.

UPDATE: After looking at the data again and noticing a comment from @Anony-Mousse, I assume that the question is: given three categories A, B, C and their respective values and labels (Ids), cluster them according to some similarity metric (it can be euclidian distance, cosine distance or some other). I am updating my previous answer to match the aforementioned assumptions.

Parse the data and generate three numerical or one-hot encoded features that represent the values for categories A, B, and C for each Id.

> K: input
>
> Repeat until convergence:
>
> - Initialize 3-dimensional cluster centroids U1 to Uk randomly.
> - For each Id find smallest sum of euclidian distances between category values and the cluster centroids. Assign that cluster centroid as the
>   new cluster center of the current Id.
> - For each cluster recompute its centroid by averaging features of all the samples (Ids) assigned to it.

Convergence can be when cluster centroids do not change or when each centroid changes less than a small value provided as an input.

Comment: No. That way he still has three rows per id!

Comment: I assumed that the data will be sanitized first and duplicates removed, edited my answer to include that detail.

Comment: These aren't duplicates. Every id has 1 value for each category. See my answer...

Comment: That is not what OP wants, he wants to create a cluster of ids.

Comment: Yes, and IDs each have three rows, storing *three* values A, B and C for each ID... I didn't make up the pivot operation. It's a built-in... Check out what it does, and you'll see that it's the proper thing to do here.

Comment: Looking at the data again, it appears what OP wants is the similarity between three categories - A, B and C for each Id as you commented. I have updated my answer to reflect that.